# How to send an OPTIONS HTTP Method in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, nsmutableurlrequest

I am working for a company that has an HTTP OPTIONS method as one of their routes. How do I send an HTTP OPTIONS method in iOS, either using NSMutableURLRequest, AFNetworking, or some other library? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

`NSMutableHTTPURLRequest`, which is actually an informal protocol on `NSMutableURLRequest`, includes this property:

`@property (copy) NSString *HTTPMethod;`

This is the HTTP request type. You can set this to `@"OPTIONS"`.